# Make a google calendar event the same time everyday without a repeating event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a google calendar which I would like to have the same event repeat every day. The event goes from 8 to 9 AM PST and I can't make it a repeating event in google calendar. I have a calendar id for it and I was wondering what the Google Apps Script code should be.

Thanks

Edit:
The code that I have so far is this:

```
function newFunction() {
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('mycalendarid@group.calendar.google.com')
//need start and end as date formats

for(i=0; i<30; i++){
cal.createEvent('Test', start,end)
var start = start+1
var end = end+1
}
}
```

I just need a way to make a date that can be used in creating google calendar events and I can preform addition with

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I can't make it a repeating event in google calendar.`? From your tag of `google-apps-script`, do you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script? If it's so and your issue is included in the script, can you provide your script? By this, it will help users think of your issue and the solution.

Comment: Have u looked at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEventSeries(String,Date,EventRecurrence,Object))

Comment: I just updated the post. There is my code so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the [createAllDayEventSeries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventseriestitle,-startdate,-recurrence,-options) method, for that you'd first need to create an [EventOcurrence](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence) object with daily rule. Here's an example code I made and it worked successfully creating a recurring event for everyday in March.

```
function myFunction() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('[CALENDAR-ID]')
  var startDate = new Date('March 1, 2020 03:00:00 PM EST');
  var endDate = new Date('March 30, 2020')
  var ocurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().until(endDate);

  var eventSeries = cal.createAllDayEventSeries('No Meetings', startDate, ocurrence, {guests: 'everyone@example.com'});  
  Logger.log('Event Series ID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
}
```